# SQL query to find column value contains all vowels

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to filter the row which contains all vowels in the column value.
for example, the table letters contains list of column value.

```
str
----
apple
orange
education
```

I tried the sql with like command.

```
select str from letters 
 where 
    str like '%a%'
    and str like '%e%'
     and str like '%i%'
      and str like '%o%'
       and str like '%u%'
```

Would like to know is there any better way to handle this?
Expected output is : education

Comment: If you mean "better" as faster or better readable, I think the answer is no. If you mean "better" as "safer", write "where lower(str) like..."

Comment: You can use TRANSLATE to replace all the vowels with an empty string. If the result is then an empty string/null you know the original string contained only vowels

Comment: @JonasMetzler. instead of multiple like command, is it possible to approach regex or any other builtin functions

Comment: Ok, I must admit I was wrong. The idea of a_horse_with_no_name is quite clever, although I prefer to avoid such queries in SQL. That's a better task for applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use arrays for that

the build in array function `@>` means contains, which does exactly what you want, so all values from the `ARRAY['a','e','i','o','u']` must be in the array `regexp_split_to_array(str, '\s*')`

[manual array functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-array.html)

a_horse_with_no_name write in the comments

> regexp_split_to_array(str, '\s*') can be simplified to string_to_array(str, null)

so i added it to the answer

```
SELECT * FROm table1
  WHERE 
  regexp_split_to_array(str, '\s*') @> ARRAY['a','e','i','o','u']
```

| str |
| --- |
| education |

> ```
> SELECT 1
> ```

```
SELECT * FROm table1
  WHERE
string_to_array(str, null) @> ARRAY['a','e','i','o','u']
```

| str |
| --- |
| education |

> ```
> SELECT 1
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/d9ejPPJN)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. Can you please explain '@> ARRAY['a'..]. what it will do

Comment: `regexp_split_to_array(str, '\s*')` can be simplified to `string_to_array(str, null)`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ilike all()` to make that shorter

```
select str 
from letters 
where str ilike all (array['%a%', '%e%' , '%i%', '%o%', '%u%'])
```